# Lower limit of supremum of sequence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, by the way $\exists M\geq 0$ so that $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in X$.

Prove that
$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}{(\sup\limits_{x\in X}{f_n(x)})}\geq\sup\limits_{x\in X}{(\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}{f_n(x)})}$.

I've no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ (it
is real-valued because $f_{n}$ is uniformly bounded). Let $y\in X$
and $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{k\geq n}f_{k}(y)>g(y)-\varepsilon$,
there exists $N$ such that $\inf_{k\geq n}f_{k}(y)>g(y)-\varepsilon$
whenever $n\geq N$. In particular, $f_{k}(y)>g(y)-\varepsilon$ whenever
$k\geq N$. Clearly, for each $k\geq N$, $\sup_{x\in X}f_{k}(x)\geq f_{k}(y)>g(y)-\varepsilon$.
Therefore, for any $n\geq N$, $\inf_{k\geq n}\left(\sup_{x\in X}f_{k}(x)\right)\geq g(y)-\varepsilon.$
It follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{k\geq n}\left(\sup_{x\in X}f_{k}(x)\right)\geq g(y)-\varepsilon$.
That is, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in X}f_{n}(x)\right)\geq g(y)-\varepsilon$.
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in X}f_{n}(x)\right)\geq g(y).$
Finally, since $y\in X$ is arbitrary too, we have that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in X}f_{n}(x)\right)\geq\sup_{y\in X}g(y)=\sup_{x\in X}\left(\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)\right).$

Comment: Remark: Actually, $X$ needs not be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. $X$ can be any non-empty set.